# Binding DataGridComboBoxColumn to an enum declared inside a class

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a datagrid thats bound to my database: [image: Member Datagrid] 
I want the gender column to be a combobox with its selected value coming from the database. Gender is an enum inside the Member class:

```
namespace Elysium.model
{ 
    class Member
    {
        public enum MemberType { Standard, Premium }
        public enum Status { Inactive, Active }
        public enum Gender { Male, Female }
```

I have tried to bind it the following way but it gives me an error that Gender is not defined in the namespace or nesting is not allowed when I do `<x:Type TypeName="local.Member:Gender" ></x:Type>` :

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="genderEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type LocalValueEnumerator}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:Gender" ></x:Type>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

ViewMembers.xaml:

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource memberViewSource}">
    <DataGrid x:Name="memberDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" Width="1100" Height="600">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="memberIDColumn" Binding="{Binding MemberID}" Header="Member ID" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="fatherNameColumn" Binding="{Binding FatherName}" Header="Father Name" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="genderColumn" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Value}" Header="Gender" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
```

ViewMembers.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class ViewMembers : Page
{
    DataTable memberTable = new DataTable();

    public ViewMembers()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MemberDatabase members = MemberDatabase.getApplicationDatabase();
        memberTable = members.getAllMembers();
        memberDataGrid.ItemsSource = memberTable.DefaultView;
    }
```

Project Structure:

[image: Project Architecture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ObjectType` should be set to `System.Enum`:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="genderEnum" 
                    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                    MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="local:Gender" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Usage:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="genderColumn"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource genderEnum}}" ... />
```

Comment: it gives me an error that gender does not exist in the namespace. Gender is inside the Member class and when I do Member.Gender it says that nested types are not supported.

Comment: I was able to remove the error by restarting visual studio. the combobox has gender values now but the selected value is blank and whenever I select a value and click outside, the value disappears.

Comment: @MarijKhan: That's another issue. Please ask a new question and close this one.